# Hyperlink on database varchar column

Tags: php, mysql

I have an insert into to the database and the text I insert have `<a href=""></a>` tags.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pm`(`message`) VALUES('You have been Invited to the team hello Click <a href="http://localhost:8080/competitive/accept.php">here</a> to accept.')");
```

and the result of the echo from the column is something like this:

```
You have been Invited to the team hello Click href="http://localhost:8080/competitive/accept.php">here to accept.
```

And I want it to looks like this:

```
You have been Invited to the team hello Click here/*this is an link*/ to accept.
```

How do I make it properly?

**edit:**

full code: http://jsfiddle.net/Mvpy8/ ps: dont run just see the code.

Comment: I am surprised that the INSERT works at all, as you have to escape the `"` chars to `\"`. How are you outputting the text, using `echo` or something like that?

Comment: change `'.$team_name.'` to `".$team_name."` and change `<a href="http://localhost:8080/competitive/accept.php">here</a> to accept.'` to `<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/competitive/accept.php\">here</a> to accept.'`. ***[HINT]*** add a back-slash in front of dbl quotes.

Comment: or just store the link in the field, and then when you retrieve it wrap an <a> tag around it in the echo statement. Easier than escaping values in and out of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as expected:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pm` (`message`) VALUES ('You have been Invited to the team ".$team_name." Click <a href=\"http://localhost:8080/competitive/accept.php\">here</a> to accept.')");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `message` FROM `pm` LIMIT 1");
if($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

But you should use mysqli instead of mysql.

If this does not work, post the exact code you are encountering the problem with!

Comment: The full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mvpy8/ dont run it, its just for you see

Comment: If using single quotes (`'`) to encapsulate the string, you do not have to escape the double quotes (`"`). But the problem seems to lie with your output. Where is the code that outputs the row?

Comment: Ahhh, I see. My guess is that the `wordwrap`-function breaks up the html-tag. Look at the source output of your script, I guess there will be something like `<a <br />href="` which breaks your link.

Comment: oh yeeee oh thanks didnt noticed that, now I putted the wrap for 150 characters and worked. :/ sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your usage of ' and ". Try this.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `pm`(`message`) VALUES('You have been Invited to the team ".$team_name." Click <a href='http://localhost:8080/competitive/accept.php'>here</a> to accept.')");
```

Comment: Now looks like this `You have been Invited to the team hello Click href=\'http://localhost:8080/competitive/accept.php\'>here to accept.`